# PhpStorm AutoComplete code is not working

Tags: ide, phpstorm, code-completion

I'm using PhpStorm over 3 months and it's a good IDE. I do not know what I've clicked yesterday but since yesterday I have issue with code completion in CSS mainly.

On the screen I have VS Code and PhpStorm and also I've opened the same project.

[image: PhpStorm]

[image: VSCode]

In VS Code it works perfectly. In PhpStorm it doesn't. I tried some Google First Aid like clear cache, update the IDE, turn On/Off Safe mode etc. but nothing changed.

My Code Completion settings:

[image: PhpStorm Settings]

Comment: IDE's inner power save mode prevents full range of code inspections.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your PhpStorm editor area screenshot (many thanks for that BTW: not many people do post it even if asked), all your CSS files are treated as a Plain Text. It's rather unlikely to be a glitch, more like accidental settings change.

1. `Settings/Preferences | Plugins` -- make sure that CSS plugin is enabled. If not -- enable and restart the IDE.

   [image]
2. If still the same: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` -- locate "Cascading style sheet" entry and make sure that it has `*.css` pattern there.

   If not there -- it's possible that you have *somehow* reassigned it to "Text" file type. If it's there -- just add `*.css` to **Cascading style sheet** patterns (it will remove it from Text when doing that).

   [image]

If still nothing: you would need to provide more/new screenshots.

Comment: Hello, still nothing. What ScreensShots do u need pls?

Comment: @PetrHasil 1) The editor again -- need to see how it looks now. 2) The file types 9for "Cascading style sheet", "Text", "File type auto-detected" and other 2 "Files opened/supported..." entries after that 3) Locate such not working .css file in the Project View panel and then invoke "View | Quick Documentation" on it (should be `Ctrl+Q` on default Windows and Linux keymaps) -- show the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Reason can easily be IDE's inner `power save mode` enabled.

Check that, as it stops the IDE from automatically performing the full range of battery-hungry code inspections in the background as you type.

Comment: yes, in my case, it is working in power save mode, if I disabled, it is working correctly.,